# I can't find my example xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I download Xamarin and I installed the starter version. I created one Android project.
I started up my Android app then when i browse the app, I can't find my new app

Comment: Do you mean you started the Android emulator and your app is not installed there? Did you publish it to the emulator?

Comment: when I run the app using one emulator like MonoForAndroid_API_10(emulator-5554), I can't see my example in

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the app to the emulator after starting the emulator?

At the device selection dialog, the list shows emulators that are not running in grey and emulators that are running in black. You need to select the running emulator and press the "OK" button to deploy and run the app.

Note that after you start the emulator it will take a little while for it to finihs booting and turn from grey to black in the list.